# WooCommerce image display cropping not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up my WordPress e-commerce with WooCommerce, but the images are displayed weirdly. In `customize > WooCommerce > product images`, i've set the `thumbnail crop` to be `1:1`, to make product images the same size. Yet, they are being displayed as if i had selected `not cropped`.

The weirdest part is that this bug only happens on the live site, while the localhost test environment behaves normally.

Wordpress version: `5.1.1` (on both localhost and live site)

WooCommerce version: `3.5.7` (on both localhost and live site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wooCommerce weren't able to resize images because my server didn't have the php GD lib. Install it and the images will be cropped automatically.